# Kafka fails to publish message when any node in a 3 node cluster is down

Tags: apache-kafka

I have kafka 0.10.2.1 deployed in a 3 node cluster with default configuration for the most part. The Producer config is as follows,

```
        "bootstrap.servers", 3;
        "retry.backoff.ms", "1000"
        "reconnect.backoff.ms", "1000"
        "max.request.size", "5242880"
        "key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer"
        "value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer"
```

What I am seeing is that when one node in the cluster is down I cannot publish messages to Kafka anymore. I get the following exception when I do so,

```
05-Apr-2018 22:29:33,362 PDT ERROR [vm18] [KafkaMessageBroker] (default task-43) |default| Failed to publish message for topic deviceConfigRequest: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for deviceConfigRequest-1: 30967 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.valueOrError(FutureRecordMetadata.java:70) [kafka-clients-0.10.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:65) [kafka-clients-0.10.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:25) [kafka-clients-0.10.2.1.jar:]
    at x.y.x.KafkaMessageBroker.publishMessage(KafkaMessageBroker.java:151) [classes:]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Well, what's the topic replication factor? If your topic only has one replica, it doesn't matter how many brokers you have. If that one goes down, you can't produce/consume

Comment: replication factor is 3

Comment: What is `min.insync.replicas` on the broker. The default `acks` for a producer is 1, so that shouldn't stop you...although I would expect a `NotEnoughReplicas` error if it was hitting an ISR problem. What do you get when you run `bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper ZKADDRESS --topic YOURTOPIC`?

Comment: For the bootstrap.servers parameter you need to pass the addresses for each broker.

Comment: Are you using ack=all property if you are using that remove it and try it should work

Comment: It turns out that the replication factor was not correct as @cricket_007 had pointed out. Changing that fixes the issue.

Comment: Feel free to provide an answer below with how you fixed the problem